# Disable localhost postfix sending emails outside my machine

Tags: postfix, mutt

I configured postfix & mutt to read mails being sent by applications locally, but I just found out that they are going out on the internet too. Sometimes they reach my inbox and many times get marked as spam.

How do I configure postfix to not send mail outside my machine? I only want to be able to read emails through mutt.

Right now, I have this in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
myorigin = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
relayhost =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the relayhost to an nonexistent host. That way it would bounce (after some timeout) anything destined for outside your localhost.

Comment: You mean `relayhost = randomstring` will work?

Comment: I wouldn't put any random string, but I might put something like "nohost.local" and have "nohost.local" in your hosts file pointing to some local LAN IP that does not exist (do not use 127.0.0.x)